# How to show initial words of an unsaved file as title on atom editor instead of "untitled"

Tags: atom-editor

In Sublime if the file is unsaved it shows the initial words of that file as title instead of "untitled". How can I achieve this in Atom edtior? I am using Atom Editor 1.33.1 version.

E.g. If the content of my unsaved file is "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog." my title bar should show  "The quick.." instead of "untitled".

Comment: Have you tried "un-untitled", like I explained, it more accurately recreates the behaviour of Atom and Sublime Text.

Comment: I am getting below error while installing "un-untitled".

Comment: Thanks for trying it. I'm just fixing the error.

Comment: It should now work fine! Make sure you update to version 2.1.0.

Comment: Thanks. This is working now. Like you said it more accurately recreates behaviour of Atom and Sublime text.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm glad it's working. Let me know if you do have any problems.

Comment: Again getting same error. 

Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined
    at Object.activate (C:\Users\skhede\.atom\packages\un-untitled\un-untitled.js:17:44)

Comment: Are you using version 2.1.0?

Comment: Yes. I am getting this error after upgrading to Atom 1.34.0.

`code`
TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at Object.activate (C:\Users\skhede\.atom\packages\un-untitled\un-untitled.js:15:17)
    at Package.activateNow (C:\Users\skhede\AppData\Local\atom\app

`code`

Comment: I mean version 2.1.0 of the package, not Atom. I fixed the problem in the package and made a new version. You have to go into your settings and update the package to the new version. Look here: https://i.imgur.com/aLSTtkn.png. Go to Settings > Packages and look at `un-untitled`. You can see in the image, marked in orange that I have the version 2.1.0. If yours says 2.0.0 then you there should be a button there that says Update.

Comment: Yes. I was using the 2.1.0 version of un-untitled. Somehow, it seems to work today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package `un-untitled` at https://atom.io/packages/un-untitled.

It puts the first few words of the file in the tab, the window bar and the status bar, and so mirrors accurately the standard behaviour of Atom, while giving you this behaviour from Sublime Text.

`tab-title` doesn't change the status bar and the window bar loses the ending part, which normally gives you the project path and 'Atom'.

Answer (score 0):

There's a package I'm building for this--> https://atom.io/packages/auto-tab-title.

Currently works only on command (Ctrl+Shift+t) and not in background.
Trying to get that to work and removing a few kinks.

Feel free to raise PRs to improve on it @Rob, @Shashank

Comment: Good effort for making a package. I had a look at the code. You have some good stuff in there.